# ipad uisplitview: passing data from masterviewcontroller to a uiviewcontroller (redirected via segue)

Tags: xcode, ipad, uitableview, uiviewcontroller, uisplitviewcontroller

I'm new to iOS programming so I want to make this thing from scratch to be able understand how the whole thing works. So instead of using the master detail template I did this from the ground up.

I'm having a huge roadblock in terms of passing data between the master view and the detail view. At the moment, whenever I tap on the item of the master view it would look for the first view on the detail view controller, let's call it `mainswitchviewcontroller`. It's the first `ViewController` connected via segue to the `UINavigationController` for the detail controller part (Please refer to image below).

This happens after login where it shows that `viewcontroller`, I want the user to pick an option before accessing the whole app. which will lead them to the last `ViewController` of the flow (refer to the image below - red circle).

[image: Flow diagram]

Now what I'm trying to do is this:

```
@interface MasterListViewController : UITableViewController{
}

@property (nonatomic) int matNum;
@property (strong, nonatomic) DetailStaffMainContentViewController *detailViewController;
@end

:
:

@implementation MasterListViewController
@synthesize matNum;
:
:
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{

    for(UIViewController *vc in self.splitViewController.viewControllers){
        NSLog(@"%@)", vc.title);
    }

    self.detailViewController.teststring = @"gronk";
}
```

This is my detailViewController (the one I want to access)

```
@implementation DetailStaffMainContentViewController
@synthesize tableView;
@synthesize teststring;
@synthesize lblOutput;
```

Now on select of the row, I assign the `teststring` which I want to use to populate that label on the controller. That's what I did.

My questions are:

1. I'm getting an error. Wondering what I was doing wrong?

   ```
   [MainSwitchBoardViewController setTeststring:]: unrecognized selector
   sent to instance 0x7572190
   ```
2. Is this a recommended way of passing data? Or should I just stick with notificationcenters?

Thoughts?

**EDIT**
Just to give you on the flow of the app:

1. User logs in (if username does not exist, the floating viewcontroller will pop up and force the user to log in.
2. Once the user logs in, the pop up goes away and then asks the user what type of role is to be used in the current session (eg. staff or fighter).
3. If the user picks fighter, it pushes the user to the top VC    If the user picks staff, it pushes the user to the bottom VC (collections controller)
4. FOR Staff: At the moment I'm pushing to the last VC with this  [self perfermSegueWithIdentifier:sender:self]

   Once the user gets shown the last VC (DetailsStaffView), I want this to be the main Details View where the user does it's transaction. A few more pop ups? (Or maybe another push to another VC for specific transaction needs to be added). But ultimately I **don't want** the user to access the **first Viewcontroller (MasterSwitchBoard)**

**EDIT 2**
This is the main switch board class that controls the first VC after login.

```
@interface MainSwitchBoardViewController : UIViewController{

}

@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *txtLabel;
- (IBAction)btnStaff:(id)sender;
- (IBAction)btnAdmin:(id)sender;

@end
```

This is the collections VC which atm automatcially pushes to the last VC. In the beginning I was using a notification on this but it seems like it's not necessary so I took it out.

```
@interface MatListCollectionViewController ()

@end

@implementation MatListCollectionViewController
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.

    [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"SeguePushToStaffDetailFromMats" sender:self];
}
```

And then the details staff

```
@interface DetailStaffMainContentViewController : UIViewController{

}

@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITableView *tableView;
@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UILabel *lblOutput;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString *teststring;

@end


    @implementation DetailStaffMainContentViewController
    @synthesize tableView;
    @synthesize teststring;
    @synthesize lblOutput;
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'll tackle those in reverse order:

> Is this a recommended way of passing data? Or should I just stick with notificationcenters?

You theoretically could use notification center, but I wouldn't in this case. Personally, I only use `NSNotificationCenter` if:

- I'm doing asynchronous process which has no reasonable way of knowing the state of the view controllers (e.g. I have some background task that's doing some time consuming update of data from a server, and the user could have navigated to just about anywhere in the app by the time I'm ready to notify the view controllers that the update is done); and/or
- I potentially have multiple objects that I want to notify of some event.

Neither of those conditions apply here. Certainly you could use `NSNotificationCenter`, but that should be unnecessary. Explicitly setting properties is generally preferable.

> I'm getting an error. Wondering what I was doing wrong?

Unfortunately, it's hard to say on the basis of the evidence you've presented thus far. But there are a few things that I'm having trouble reconciling on the basis of your code and comments:

- You've declared `detailViewController` to be a `DetailStaffMainContentViewController` (and that's the class for which you've synthesized the `teststring` accessors);
- But your error message suggests that `detailViewController` is clearly a `MainSwitchBoardViewController` object (which doesn't understand the `setTeststring` accessor method); and
- You haven't shown us how you're setting `detailViewController`, so it's hard to say where you've gone wrong here.

Personally, in cases like this, I'm always reticent to define properties to maintain pointers to view controllers. I'd generally be inclined to ask the `UISplitViewController` what's in the `detail` split. So, rather than having a class property/ivar for that, in my master view controller, I have a method like:

```
- (UIViewController *)detailViewController
{
    return [[self.splitViewController.viewControllers lastObject] topViewController];
}
```

That's basically saying "get the last object from my split view controller's array of `viewControllers` (the detail split) and because I (personally) always use a navigation controller in that detail split, let's use the `topViewController` to get a pointer to my subclassed `UIViewController` that's in that detail split (embedded within the navigation controller).

Then I have my `didSelectRowAtIndexPath` check to see if that view controller is the one I expected. If not, I segue to it (and have `prepareSegue` pass the data I want to that controller).

So, for example, consider this storyboard:

[image: sample storyboard]

Here, "A" is my default detail controller. "B" might be some random scene that I may have replaced "A" with. And "C" is my real detail view controller where I can see the details for the item I selected from the master view controller's table view. Thus, my `didSelectRowAtIndexPath` for the master view controller might look like:

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    UIViewController *controller = [self detailViewController];

    if (![controller isKindOfClass:[DetailCViewController class]])
    {
        // if I'm not already showing "C" in my detail split, then let's segue to it

        [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"GoToC" sender:self];
    }
    else
    {
        // if I'm already showing "C" in my detail split, let's just set the item of data I want to pass to it

        DetailCViewController *cController = (DetailCViewController *)controller;

        cController.detailItem = self.objects[indexPath.row];
    }

    // I have a method I call to make sure that the popover menu for the master view
    // controller disappears (in case it popped up since I was in portrait mode) and
    // adds the master view controller button to the navigation bar if I need it.

    [self removePopoverAndAddNavigationButton];
}
```

In case I needed to segue to "C", I also have my `prepareSegue pass the detailItem as needed:

```
- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender
{
    if ([segue.identifier isEqualToString:@"GoToC"])
    {
        DetailCViewController *cController = (DetailCViewController *)[segue.destinationViewController topViewController];

        cController.detailItem = self.objects[[[self.tableView indexPathForSelectedRow] row]];
    }
}
```

As I said, trying to figure out why your `detailViewController` has the wrong type of object is hard to say, but this is how I might tackle something like this.

Comment: Hey Rob, thanks for taking the time in answering my question! It really helped me understand a few things. And yeah that's what I noticed on the error, even thought it was pushed to the last VC it would still consider it as the masterswitchboard(first VC connected to the UiNav). In case you're wondering,the views gets pushed via segue from the mainswitch to the collection view(2nd UIView) and then pushed again via [self perfermSegueWithIdentifier:sender:self] to the last view. Which doesn't make sense to me. Is pushing a VC just places the VC on top of the main detail?and does not replace it?

Comment: @gdubs Yes, navigation controllers use a "stack" metaphor, where each "push" adds a view controller on top of the others, and each "pop" removes from the top of the stack (kind of like the "back" button on your web browser). That's often a really useful technique, so you can pop back to precisely where you were in the last VC. When dealing with `UISplitViewCongtroller`, though, you have an additional option of a "replace" segue, which does precisely as the name suggests, not saving the previous controller in that particular "split" (i.e. the master split or the detail split).

Comment: So I updated the question. Now I'm wondering if I should completely replace that mainswitchboard so that it goes completely away. Since I dont want that accessed after the user gets to the last VC (detailstaffview). Also, do you think I should just remove that mainswitchboard and just connect it with the login vc (floating one) since they're like config steps before anyone can use the app really..

Comment: My bad, updated with codes as well. Also for this part on your answer >> - (UIViewController *)detailViewController .. is that gonna be a method I need to declare on the interface file? Or do i just place a new property and then have this method populate such property?

Comment: @gdubs That method, `detailViewController` is just included in the .m file of your master controller. In my code I don't generally put it in the interface, as I don't use it outside of the master view controller class. In terms of your "mainswitchboard", I'm not quite sure what this scene does, so it's hard for me to answer that.

Comment: that makes sense. The mainswitchboard is just a middleman between the user and the main detailpage where they select which viewcontroller is right for them. Either the top one or the bottom one. In this case it's the bottom one. Once clicked/tapped,the use gets pushed to the the Collections Controller (black one) then pushed to the DetailsStaffController (the one where I'm having problems with)

Comment: @gdubs let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/24776/discussion-between-rob-and-gdubs) if you'd like. Extended discussions in comments is discouraged, but chat is a fine venue for that.

Comment: Awesome. Those tips helped me solve how to get data do my detailviewcontroller past the NavigationController. Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

Maybe you should first take a look at some nice [movies from the last WWDC](https://developer.apple.com/videos/wwdc/2012/) where they describe Storyboard Segues.

In the code you provided there is nothing written about segues. Be sure to use segues either via IB or programmatically via `[self performSegueWithIdentifier:]`. [See Apple Docs](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UIViewController_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006926-CH3-DontLinkElementID_4)

Then you can provide additional operations in yout view controller:

- `[view shouldPerformSegueWithIdentifier:sender:]`
- `[view prepareForSegue:sender:]`

The first one decides whether to perform the segue or not. The second one is executed just before segue is performed. Within the secon operation you can provide information to the destinationViewController.

```
- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender
{
    if([segue.identifier isEqualToString:@"showIssuesByProject"]){
        if (_searchActive) {
            ((IssueListViewController *)segue.destinationViewController).project = [_filteredProjects projectAtIndex:[self.tableView indexPathForSelectedRow].row];
        } else {
            ((IssueListViewController *)segue.destinationViewController).project = [_projects projectAtIndex:[self.tableView indexPathForSelectedRow].row];
        }
    }
    if ([segue.identifier isEqualToString:@"showIssuesByFilter"]) {
        ((IssueListViewController *)segue.destinationViewController).filter = [_filters filterAtIndex:[self.tableView indexPathForSelectedRow].row];
    }
}
```

Be careful: UISplitViewControll.viewControllers are only two controllers: the master and detail ones.

Comment: Oh, my bad, I skipped that push of the segue. It actually happens on that "black viewcontroller" it's a collections viewcontroller that pushes it there. I skipped it as I wanted to make sure data gets passed between master and detail. And that part of the flow doesn't need to get in touch with the end viewcontoller. The crash actually occurs in this line     **self.detailViewController.teststring = @"gronk";**

Comment: The error message means that self.destinationViewController has no method setTeststring. Usually this means that the controller has no property teststring if it is synthesized in the default way. As i see in your code everything should be fine so the only error scenario available is: self.detailViewController is not a DetailStaffMainContentViewController as declared. you should check this in debug mode first

Comment: @gdubs If you're pushing the "detail" split to that new scene, you can bypass the navigation controller (since you already have one). If you're replacing the "detail" split, you may want to replace starting with the navigation controller. (Often with split views, you have a left button in the nav bar that shows a popover of the master view controller, so it's frequently useful to keep the nav bar around.) Clearly, do whatever you want, but I generally make sure I keep a nav bar around in the detail split to make it a little easier.

Comment: @Rob yeah that's what I was trying to do. BTW, I updated the question to give you an idea on how I want the flow to work. I'm currently trying to understand splitviews using the wwdc 102 session. It seems like that's what you were recommending, replacing the thing with a new set of views that has it's own UINav? Either I'm on track or completely lost. lol